# Doing terraform script test with terratest but facing errors exit status 1

Tags: go, terraform, devops, terratest

I am using terratest to test terraform, I want to make sure that the terraform  makes the resource group,container registry and AKS, When I do go test -v -timeout 60m all the resources are made and destroyed but at the end I dont know why it throws

```
TestTerraformAzureResources 2024-02-09T18:45:51+05:00 logger.go:66: 
Destroy complete! Resources: 4 destroyed.
TestTerraformAzureResources 2024-02-09T18:45:51+05:00 logger.go:66: 
--- FAIL: TestTerraformAzureResources (691.95s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    my-terratest-project    691.996s
```

Below is my terraform_test.go code

```
package test

import (
"testing"

"github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
"github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestTerraformAzureResources(t *testing.T) {
terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
    TerraformDir: "../terraform scripts",
})

defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

// Retrieve the outputs of the Terraform configuration
resourceGroupName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "resource_group_name")
acrName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "acr_name")
aksName := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "aks_name")

// Define the expected values
expectedResourceGroupName := "microservice-deployment-demo-tf- 
scripttest"
expectedACRName := "microserviceimagestfscripttest"
expectedAKSName := "example-aks1-tf-scripttest"

// Compare the outputs with the expected values
assert.Equal(t, expectedResourceGroupName, resourceGroupName, "Resource 
group name does not match")
assert.Equal(t, expectedACRName, acrName, "Azure Container Registry name 
does not match")
assert.Equal(t, expectedAKSName, aksName, "Azure Kubernetes Cluster name 
does not match")
}
```

Edited :
Below are the errors I revived
Error: Received unexpected error: FatalError{Underlying: error while
running command: exit status 1; Error: Output "resource_group_name" not
found The output variable requested could not be found in the state
file. If you recently added this to your configuration, be sure to run
terraform apply

Comment: I would have expected more logging from the `-v` flag to `go test`.

Comment: I am using the command go test -v -timeout 60m

Comment: do I have to make a outputs.tf file because the error is related to retrieving the named of resources?

Comment: Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                FatalError{Underlying: error while running command: exit status 1; 
                                Error: Output "resource_group_name" not found
                            
                                The output variable requested could not be found in the state file. If you
                                recently added this to your configuration, be sure to run `terraform apply`,

Comment: Please post the entire error in your Question

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I solved the issue as it was because of some mistakes in the outputs.tf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adjusting the outputs.tf file, Configuring it in such a way that it store the values like aks named etc in variables.
Below is the outputs.tf file

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.demoresourcegroup.name
}

output "acr_name" {
  value = azurerm_container_registry.acr.name
 }

output "aks_name" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.name
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).